# RPG Doors / Events

Tags: c#, 2d

Heeeey, on my RPG i'm working on i have a working tile engine which you can add layers, i have three layers:

- Bottom Layer
- Top Layer
- Solid Layer

I have collision working and also the character animation working.

But how would i go making doors, that when you walk into them and have a key, it switches to another map?

I tried to add another layer called "EventLayer" but i don't know how to format it properly to work.. And things like **Events** - For example a falling book, sound effect...

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This question must be a better fit for [gamedev.se].

Answer (score 2):

Events like this will be a lot different based on what exactly you need in your game. 
If you want events to only be doors and similar interactable objects, and have NPCs and monsters etc. in their own type, then events are not that tough to make.

You need to include every property you need to have for all your events, such as the position, graphic and trigger type. In your case, you want certain events only to function when certain items are in possession. Add a requirement list, and make sure everything in that list is met before executing the corresponding event.

When programming your event objects, you might want to make them universal, so you can create most (if not all) of your events from this instances of this class. Example of a quick event class mockup:

```
class Event {
    public Texture2D Graphic { get; set; }
    public Vector2 TileLocation { get; set; }
    public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    public TriggerType Trigger { get; set; }
    public List<Command> Commands { get; set; }
    public int CommandIndex { get; set; }
    public bool Running { get; set; }
    public bool Erased { get; set; }

    public Event() { Erased = false; }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime){
       if(Erased) return;
       if(Running){ 
          // continue command execution 
       }
       else // check for triggering
          switch(Trigger){ }
    }

    public void Draw()[
       if(Erased) return;
       // drawing code
    }
}
```

The command class and the TriggerType enum should not be an issue.

I hope this helps you get what you wanted. It's a bit hard to tell you exactly how you should do it based on such little information. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Sarkilas, and it don't really want to know EXACTLY either :D
You learn more by trying yourself, but sometimes i only need a little help with the concept of making something.. :P
I'll expermient with this, i'll be back when i got something! :D

Comment: Just a question, is it possible to put everything in the same class?
And then in Game1.cs:

Event doorOpen = new Event(//Insert variable values here..);

Something like that? (please note that this is my first time working on an RPG game, since im a beginner..)

Comment: What do you mean put everything in the same class? You mean not having additional classes such as Condition, Command etc? I wouldn't recommend it. Add commands in a list beforehand, such as "new Command("sound", "door.ogg"); new Command("transfer", "new_map");" or stuff like that, then construct the event after that in the same fashion that you showed in your example above (new Event()), although I'd keep my events within an event layer within your map data class. More structured.

Comment: Ok Thanks! i'll have to keep trying to add an Event layer to the tile engine.

Comment: Event layers should just be a list of events, or if you have A LOT of events (like thousands per map), then you should probably use a better indexer so you don't have to iterate every single event every update/draw. But if you have less than like a few hundred events, then a list is fine.

Comment: The events i've been thinking on is:
Door opening.
Sound effects.
AI spawn.
And something like falling book or something.

I don't have time to try coding for the moment, but in an hour i'll give it a shot :)

Comment: I cannot manage to get it right...and also my save files for it got deleted by my virus scanner O.o

Is there any internet tutorial?